# Cant import facebook unity sdk

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I have tried two unitypackage files, `140140` and `131121` and both say

```
error importing Unity package, format not supported.
```

I am using Win XP, and have [Unity 4.5.1](http://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-4.5.1) installed.

Anyone know what could be wrong?

cheers Kirk

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work!!!  I started the Unity editor first the used import package, and it installed fine

before I was clicking on the unitypackage file itself -doh!

so answered my own question